# My media queries is not working and I don't know why. It's my first time using media queries

Tags: css, media-queries

I've just started practicing media queries and I am not sure why the code below is not working. Media Queries is very new to me, so excuse me if my question seems stupid. I'm writing the code for a smart phone. Thanks

Here's the html

```
<head>
    <link href="portfolio.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="intro">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">SKILLS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MY WORK</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ABOUT ME</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

And the CSS

```
@media and (max-device-width:500px) {
    .intro {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        height: 400px;
    }

    .intro .menu li {
        display: inline-block;

    }

    .intro .menu li a {
        font-family: "Arial Rounded MT Bold", "Helvetica Rounded", Arial, sans-serif;
        color: #fff;
    }
}
```

Comment: remove `and` from `@media and (max-device-width:500px) {`

Comment: If you are practicing with media queries, may I suggest using `max-width` instead of `max-device-width`, so you can see what happens when you resize the window with the mouse.

Comment: `max-device-width` has been deprecated, use `max-width`

Comment: @LGSon Deprecated? Then what are we supposed to be using for screen width?

Comment: @MrLister ... jQuery? ... ;) .... Here are some recommendations: https://www.w3.org/TR/mediaqueries-4/#mf-deprecated

Comment: @LGSon OK... While they may have a point about a) harvesting device info that the user doesn't realise is harvested, and b) the webpage  author should be concerned with the window, not the screen size, I do think knowing the screen size does have its advantages. Oh well. Hey JavaScript, I've got another job for you!

Answer (score 0):

**Remove "and" from your code you need to use like this:-**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){

}
```

Your media query use only for the specific browser like safari and opera.

```
@media only screen and (max-device-width:500px){

}
```